# Error: We're sorry, but something went wrong. Simple JRuby on Rails Program on Tomcat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, tomcat, jrubyonrails, warbler

**situation:**

- Environment: Windows 8, JRuby 1.7.3, Rails 3.2.13, ...
- I'm trying to run a sample program from a JRuby on Rails teaching book

**so far:**

1. Created Simple Ruby on Rails project "answerme" with MySQL
2. Edited to `config.assets.compile = true` in config/environments/producton.rb
3. Created "answerme.war" file by the command "warble war"
4. Put the .war file into "Tomcat 7.0/webapps/" directory
5. Run Tomcat, then it makes new directory "answerme" and files in "Tomcat 7.0/webapps/"
6. It doesn't work, `http://localhost:8080/answerme/feelings`

- This works, `http://localhost:8080`
- This works on rails ordinary server with `http://localhost:3000`

---

'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\logs\localhost_access_log.2013-05-07.txt'

```
5 07, 2013 10:47:21 午後 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
情報: Started GET "/answerme/feelings" for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 at 2013-05-07 22:47:21 +0900

5 07, 2013 10:47:21 午後 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
情報: Processing by FeelingsController#index as HTML

5 07, 2013 10:47:22 午後 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
情報:   Rendered feelings/index.html.erb within layouts/application (82.0ms)

5 07, 2013 10:47:22 午後 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
情報: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 173ms

5 07, 2013 10:47:22 午後 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
情報:
ActionView::Template::Error (no such file to load -- sass
  (in C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/webapps/answerme/WEB-INF/app/assets/stylesheets/feelings.css.scss)):
    2: <html>
    3: <head>
    4:   <title>Answerme</title>
    5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    8: </head>
  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1682700681_6054'
  app/controllers/feelings_controller.rb:7:in `index'
```